# How to rotate, override, or turn off logging from Sunspot Solr Rubygem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, logging, sunspot

I've had great experiences with Sunspot Solr search for Ruby on Rails, however, its log files are growing incredibly large and I can't seem to find a way to either **rotate**, **override**, or **turn off** these logs (other than with very hacky methods that I'd rather not pursue).

I have a file, **sunspot.yml** in **config/**, where I tried setting the **log_level** flags to **SEVERE**, however, this had no effect.

I tried using the standard **Logger.config** rotation methods, however, that just sent my **development log** output to newly created files.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions you can offer.

Comment: I'm on version 1.2 of the gem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit late, but looks like this is now handled inside config/sunspot.yml:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: thorn
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    min_memory: 512M
    max_memory: 1G
    solr_home: /u/solr
```

Comment: I am using 1.3.2 but INFO still keep showing up in production log.

Answer (score 5):

In the console, this turns off all logging for me:

```
Sunspot::Rails::LogSubscriber.logger.level = 4
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 4
Rails.logger.level = 4
```

My Gem versions:

- sunspot (2.0.0.pre.130115)
- sunspot_rails (2.0.0.pre.130115)
- sunspot_solr (2.0.0.pre.130115)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the Solr `logging.properties` file to customize the Java container's logging behavior. Sunspot uses Jetty for its embedded Solr instance. The Solr wiki provides instructions for customizing `logging.properties` in Jetty at 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LoggingInDefaultJettySetup.

You may need to review the source code for Sunspot's rake tasks to determine the best place to inject your own `logging.properties`. I imagine this would be an interesting question to raise on the [Sunspot mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-sunspot) for a potential patch to Sunspot.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the log_level is not handled correctly. [The fix is on Github](https://github.com/lulalala/sunspot/commit/e96ab525ed85096c6d40f84941f680a7a3e7d4a5), which is a 2.x release.

You can wait for the next gem release. And if you don't and is not afraid of risk, you can use the following in the Gemfile:

```
# use selectively
gem 'sunspot_rails', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require =>  "sunspot_rails"
gem 'sunspot_solr', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require => "sunspot_solr"
```

I use Linux logrotate:

```
/home/path/log/*.log {
  su username pwd
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 7
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've monkey patched the appropriate file in sunspot_solr to resolve this exact issue.

This code is not robust enough to survive rearchitecting/refactoring done directly in the sunspot_solr gem, so I recommend locking your sunspot_solr gem version to 1.3.0 for this to succeed.

You can drop the following into your project.  We use it in a Rails project and have placed it at lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:

```
module Sunspot
  module Solr
    class Server #:nodoc:

      def logging_config_path
        puts "# ==> Using monkey-patched Sunspot::Solr::Server#logging_config_path method"

        return @logging_config_path if defined?(@logging_config_path)
        @logging_config_path =
        if log_file
            logging_config = Tempfile.new('logging.properties')
            logging_config.puts("handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler")
            logging_config.puts("java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = #{log_level.to_s.upcase}")
            logging_config.puts("java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = #{log_file}")
            logging_config.puts("java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter")

            # >>> ADDED THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES FOR JAVA-BASED LOG ROTATION <<<
            logging_config.puts("java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 7")
            logging_config.puts("java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 104857600") # 100 megs

            logging_config.flush
            logging_config.close
            logging_config.path
          end
        end


      end # class Server
    end # module Solr
  end # module Sunspot
```